# How can i redirect the member when login to my webapp in python

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0, discord.py

i have the runtime error.

> RuntimeError: The session is unavailable because no secret key was set.  Set the secret_key on the application to something unique and secret.

```
@app.route('/login')
def login():
    discord = make_session(scope=scope_req)
    re_authorization_url, state = discord.authorization_url(auth_url)
    session['oauth2_state'] = state
    return redirect(re_authorization_url)
```

Comment: So... have you tried setting the `secret_key` on the application to something unique and secret?

Answer (score 0):

Just add to your configiration

```
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "something_secret"
```